# Best smoothing for the Prime Number Theorem?

Tags: nt.number-theory, analytic-number-theory, fourier-analysis, integral-transforms

There are plenty of proofs of the Prime Number Theorem with explicit error terms - it actually looks like a rather competitive field (see Remark 1.4 in https://arxiv.org/pdf/2204.02588.pdf). Several such proofs start by defining a *smoothing function* - an approximation $\eta$ to the function $1_{[0,1]}$ (which is the function taking the value $1$ for $0\leq x\leq 1$ and the value $0$ for $x>1$).

The function used by Faber-Kadiri (https://arxiv.org/abs/1310.6374) seems to be best in its class (piecewise polynomial functions $\eta$).  But what is the best $\eta$ in general? The best bounds on PNT to date in certain ranges are given by Büthe (https://arxiv.org/pdf/1511.02032.pdf), who uses a smoothing function defined as an integral involving a Bessel function. (If he gives a proof that it is best, I've missed it.)

Of course one needs to explain what one means by "best". It seems to me reasonable to frame the problem as in [Optimizing a smoothing function with the Mellin transform in mind](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/432914/optimizing-a-smoothing-function-with-the-mellin-transform-in-mind) , though the restriction there that $f(x)=1$ for $0\leq x\leq 1$ there is merely convenient, not necessary (and one really should require $f$ to be bounded).  To repeat: how does one find $f:[0,\infty)\to \mathbb{R}$ bounded and differentiable such that
$$\int_0^\infty |f(x)-1_{[0,1]}(x)| dx + c \int_T^\infty |(Mf)'(1 + it)| \cdot(t-T)  dt$$
is minimal (for a given constant $c>0$), where $Mf$ is the Mellin transform of $f$?

(It would seem more obvious to have the second integrand be $|Mf(1+it)|$ instead of $|(Mf)'(1+it)|\cdot (t-T)$, but framing matters as we have is more robust, in that it allows for averaging methods.)

Comment: perhaps it is worthwhile to mention you are also given $T>10^6$ (based off the linked question)

Comment: Sure, you can always assume T is not small (even $T>10^9$) to simplify.

Comment: Perhaps you could write it as $\min_f \limsup_T ...$?

Comment: Hm, I can't do a brute-force computation up to just *any* $T$.

Comment: From the paper cited, the function found in Faber-Kadiri is found by calculus of variation, minimising a quotient, and imposing null derivatives at the endpoints : it happens to be that the minimum is a Legendre polynomial, this wasn't an assumption. The origin of the Bessel function appearing in Büthe's paper is explained in [another paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1410.7015.pdf) where it refers to [this paper](https://epubs.siam.org/doi/epdf/10.1137/0519027) to explain why the choice is sharp. You wish to ask a different optimisation problem by relaxing something else.  In what function space?

Comment: I should have expressed myself more carefully: the way that Faber and Kadiri set up their problem - minimizing, not an integral of the Mellin transform itself, but the $L^2$ norm of a $k$th-order derivative of the smoothing function - leads to a (Legendre) polynomial being the optimal solution.

Comment: You hope for closed form formula for the minimizer (happens rarely)? Or you would like to know an algorithm to compute an approximation of a minimizer?

Comment: Well, if there's a closed-form formula for the minimizer (or, at least, for the minimum), then I would like to know it.

Comment: I don't see a clear claim being made in Büthe, but is it the case that Büthe's choice does lead to a (somewhat complicated) closed-form minimizer for $\int_T^\infty |Mf(1+it)| dt$ under the condition that $f(x)-1_{[0,1]}$ be supported in an interval $[1,1+\delta]$?  (Short version: the Mellin transform is a Fourier transform with a change of variables, and $M(x f'(x)) = -s Mf(s)$. I'm skimming, so I may be missing something.)

Comment: OK, matters are now a little clearer to me. What Büthe is doing is using a result due to Logan, which, in effect, gives a function $f$ (in closed form!) with minimal $\int_T^\infty |M f(i t)| dt$ among the functions $f$ such that $f-1_{[0,1]}$ has support in $[e^{-\delta},e^\delta]$. That's impressive, and leads to good results, but it is not actually optimal - either in my phrasing above or for what Büthe is doing. It seems to me one can do asymptotically better.

Comment: The reason is that one can choose $f$ such that $f-1_{[0,1]}$ support broader than $[e^-\delta,e^\delta]$, yet $|f-1_{[0,1]}|_1 = o(\delta)$ (as $T$ grows).  That's not the case for Büthe's function (whose derivative is in fact discontinuous at $-\delta$ and $\delta$).

Comment: I now suspect that $\frac{1}{2} (1-\textrm{erf}((\log t)/\delta))$ is best (for $\delta$ proportional to $\sqrt{\log c T}/T$; I'll work out the constant). See the discussion in https://mathoverflow.net/questions/432914/optimizing-a-smoothing-function-with-the-prime-number-theorem-in-mind . Büthe's choice (from Logan) is actually very close to this, because $I_0(C \sqrt{1-x^2})/e^C \sim e^{-x^2/2}/\sqrt{2\pi C}$ for $C$ large and $x$ small.