# Distribution $f$ such that (a) $\widehat{f}$ has compact support, (b) $\mathbb{E}(|X|)$ is minimal?

Tags: nt.number-theory, analytic-number-theory, fourier-analysis, fourier-transform

(What follows is motivated by an answer to [Fourier optimization problem related to the Prime Number Theorem](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/433612/fourier-optimization-problem-related-to-the-prime-number-theorem?noredirect=1#comment1116702_433612))

Let $f:\mathbb{R}\to [0,\infty)$ be such that

(a) $\int_{\mathbb{R}} f(x) dx = 1$,
(b) $\widehat{f}(t)=0$ for all real $t$ with $|t|>1$.

What is the choice of $f$ such that $$\int_{\mathbb{R}} |x| f(x) dx$$is minimal? What is that minimum?

Remarks:

1. It is easy to see that we can assume $f$ to be an even function.
2. Yes, this seems to be yet another incarnation of the uncertainty principle.

Comment: Why "$|\widehat{f}(t)|=0$", not $\widehat{f}(t)=0$?

Comment: Late-at-night posting. It is not incorrect...

Comment: By duality this is the same value as $\max \inf(|x|+q(x))$, where $q$ is the trigonometric generalized polynomial with frequencies at least 1

Comment: If $g:=f^{1/2}$, you're trying to minimize $\|g\|_{\dot{H}^{1/2}(\mathbb{R})}$ under the constraint $\|g\|_2=1$ with $\widehat{g^2}$ compactly supported ; you could maybe look in the direction of best constants for Sobolev embeddings

Comment: @AymanMoussa Explain?

Answer (score 3):

One can prove that under your assumptions
$$A:=\int_{-\infty}^\infty|x|f(x)dx\geq 9/(4\pi),$$
but estimate is not exact.

The proof is based on the formula
$$A=-\lim_{y\to 0+}\frac{1}{\pi}\frac{d}{dy}\left(y\int_{-1}^1\frac{\hat{f}(t)}{t^2+y^2}dt\right),$$
which is easy to obtain. Now for $\hat{f}$ supported on $[-1,1]$, Cramer obtained the estimate $\hat{f}(t)\leq 1-t^2/8$,
and using this estimate and $\hat{f}(0)=1$, we obtain the result.

Ref. H. Cramer, Random variables and probability distributions, Cambridge UP, 1970.

One can use a better, exact estimate for $\hat{f}$ in the work of

A. Fryntov, An extremal problem in the theory of Hermitian positive functions, Func Anal., Appl, 10, 1 (1976) 91-92;

this will improve the estimate, but still will not give the exact minimum of $A$.

Comment. A somewhat simpler but similar problem would be to miminize
$$|\hat{f}''(0)|=\int_{-\infty}^\infty x^2f(x)dx.$$
For this quantity, Fryntov implies the estimate $A\geq \pi^2$, which is probably also not exact.

Comment: A guess that in the formula for $A$  a minus sign is missing before the limit.

Comment: @Giorgio Metafune: Thanks! I corrected.

Comment: It is a very nice way to obtain to obtain this kind of estimates. I see that the   formula for A is true by solving the Dirichlet problem in the half plane with boundary data $\hat f$, using the Poisson kernel and the Fourier transform. I wonder if there is a simpler way. By the way, you forgot a "hat before $f$, in Cramesr's estimate.

Comment: @Giorgio Metafune: Thanks for pointing the misprint, I corrected. My method of deriving the formula for $A$ was to introduce one half of the Fourier transform $F(z)=\int_0^\infty e^{-izt}f(t)dt$. It is analytic in the lower half-plane. Then, since $f$ is even $\hat{f}(x)=F(x)+F(-x)$ by a change of the variable in the integral. So if we define $G(z)=F(z)$ in the lower half-plane and $G(z)=-F(-z)$ in the upper half-plane, then the resulting function $G$ will be analytic in $C\backslash[-1,1]$ tend to $0$ at infinity and on $(-1,1)$ it will have a jump $\hat{f}$.

Comment: Such function $G$ has a Cauchy integral representation, and its real part is represented by Poisson formula. Then one see by a direct computation that $A$ is the jump of derivative of $G$ at $0$.

Answer (score 1):

Warning: the following answer is (a) maybe a bit careless in a nineteenth-century sort of way, (b) missing its final step (which may be obvious to others, and/or amount to looking things up in the right table)

We are looking for an even function $g:\mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}$ with support on $[-1,1]$; we will define $f$ to be its Fourier transform. The condition $\int_{\mathbb{R}} f(x) dx=1$ becomes $g(0)=1$. What we need to minimize is the quantity
$$I = \int_{\mathbb{R}} |x| \widehat{g}(x) dx.$$
Here are two attempts to express $I$ more directly in terms of $g$.

1. The Fourier transform of $\frac{g'(t)}{2\pi i}$ equals $x \widehat{g}(x)$. We can write $|x| \widehat{g}(x) = \mathrm{sgn}(x) x \widehat{g}(x)$. The Fourier transform of $\mathrm{sgn}(x)$ is $\frac{1}{i \pi t}$ (in some sense). Hence, the Fourier transform of $|x| \widehat{g}(x)$ should be the convolution of $\frac{1}{i \pi t}$ and $\frac{g'(-t)}{2\pi i} = \frac{g'(t)}{2\pi i}$. In particular, $I$ should equal the value of the Fourier transform of $|x| \widehat{g}(x)$ at $0$, i.e.,
   $$I = \int_{\mathbb{R}} \frac{1}{i \pi t} \frac{g'(t)}{2\pi i} dt = 
   - \frac{1}{2 \pi^2} \int_{\mathbb{R}} \frac{g'(t)}{t} dt.$$
   We can assume $g'(0)=0$, so the integral above should make sense.
2. Since $I = - 2 \int_{-\infty}^0 x \widehat{g}(x) dx$, we can write
   $I = - 2\int_{-\infty}^0 \int_{-\infty}^y \widehat{g}(x) dx dy$.
   Now, the second antiderivative of $\widehat{g}(x)$ should have Fourier transform $\frac{g(t)}{(2\pi i)^2 t^2}$. Its value at $0$ equals both $-I/2$ (by definition) and
   $$\int_\mathbb{R} \frac{g(t)}{(2\pi i)^2 t^2} dt = 
   -\frac{1}{4\pi^2} \int_{\mathbb{R}} \frac{g(t)}{t^2} dt;$$
   hence,
   $$I = \frac{1}{2\pi^2} \int_{\mathbb{R}} \frac{g(t)}{t^2} dt.$$
   Of course this diverges.

At the same time, by integration by parts, $-\int_\mathbb{R} \frac{g'(t)}{t} dt$ equals $\int_\mathbb{R} \frac{g(t)-1}{t^2} dt$, which converges. So, it looks like
$$I =\frac{1}{2\pi^2} \int_\mathbb{R}  \frac{g(t)-1}{t^2} dt.$$

We recall we must also fulfill the constraint that $f$ take non-negative values. This will certainly be true if $g$ is defined as a convolution $h\ast h$, with $h$ symmetric and real-valued, as then $\widehat{h}$ will be real valued, and $\widehat{h\ast h} = \widehat{h}^2$. We can require that $h$ also be an even function, and that the support of $h$ be contained in $[-1/2,1/2]$.
I *think* these are all necessary conditions, so I am not making the search space for my optimum any smaller, but I'd be delighted if others can double-check and confirm.

So, we've reduced our problem to: find a symmetric function $h:[-1/2,1/2]\to \mathbb{R}$ with $(h\ast h)(0) = |h|_2^2 = 1$ such that
$$\int_{\mathbb{R}} \frac{(h\ast h)(t)-1}{t^2} dt$$
is minimal.

A bit of calculus variations seems to show that the optimal $h(t)$ has to have
$$\frac{1}{h(t_0)} \int \frac{\frac{1}{2} (h(t+t_0)+h(t-t_0)) - h(t_0)}{t^2} dt$$ equal to a constant independent of $t_0$, for $t_0\in (-1/2,1/2)$. Again by integration by parts, this is just
$$\frac{1}{h(t_0)} \int \frac{\frac{1}{2} (h'(t+t_0)+h'(t-t_0))}{t} dt,$$ which equals $\frac{1}{h(t_0)} H(h')(t_0)$, where $H$ is our old friend the Hilbert transform.

In other words: we are to find a (continuous) function $h:\mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}$, supported on $[-1/2,1/2]$, with $|h|_2=1$, such that $H(h')(t) = \lambda h(t)$ for all $t\in (-1/2,1/2)$ and some $\lambda$.

Surely such a function must be known (if it exists)?