# Eigenfunction of $h\mapsto H(h')|_{[-1,1]}$?

Tags: nt.number-theory, fa.functional-analysis, ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, analytic-number-theory, integral-transforms

Let $H$ be the Hilbert transform. Is there a continuous, even function $h:\mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}$ with support on $[-1,1]$ such that, for some $\lambda\in \mathbb{R}$,
$$H(h')(t) = \lambda h(t)$$
for all $-1< t< 1$?

What is the set of all such functions?

---

An answer would complete the solution to [Distribution $f$ such that (a) $\widehat{f}$ has compact support, (b) $\mathbb{E}(|X|)$ is minimal?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/433639/distribution-f-such-that-a-widehatf-has-compact-support-b-mathbbe) , which is itself of use for several problems related to $\zeta(s)$ and $L$-functions.

Comment: I can probably work this out as a power series $\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n x^{2 n}$ vanishing at $x=1$, but I feel like this problem must have been considered before.

Comment: Perhaps there is a simple argument showing what the avaluable value(s) of $\lambda$ are?

Comment: (Am I right in guessing that there is a solution $h$ only for $\lambda=1$?)

Comment: If I understand correctly, then $H h' = (-\Delta)^{1/2} h$, where $\Delta u = u''$ is the 1-D Laplace operator, and $h$ is just an eigenfunction of $(-\Delta)^{1/2}$ in $(-1,1)$ with zero exterior condition. There does not seem to be an explicit expression for these eigenfunctions, but they have been studied quite a lot. The minimal $\lambda$ is $1.157773\ldots$; see, for example, my paper with Bartłomiej Dyda and Alexey Kuznetsov, [DOI:10.1112/jlms.12024](https://doi.org/10.1112/jlms.12024).

Comment: @MateuszKwaśnicki Is there perhaps a nice expression for $h\ast h$?

Comment: None that I am aware of. Any explicit expression involving an eigenfunction or eigenvalue would be *very* surprising to me.

Comment: What does the spectrum look like? This question cropped up in the solution to an optimization problem (linked to in the above). The h I care about is the one that gives me a global minimum.

Comment: Regarding the spectrum: not sure what you are asking about. There is a complete set of eigenfunctions, the corresponding eigenvalues have known asymptotics, some general estimates are known too. You may have a look at the paper linked in my previous comment. Regarding the other question: honestly, I fail to understand your answer, and in particular I do not see why you expect $h * h$ to be a minimizer. (Obviously, $h$ is the minimizer when you do not require that $\hat h$ is nonnegative.)

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what is missing: it is $\widehat{h}^2$ that is required to be nonnegative, which it is, since $\widehat{h}$ is real-valued (because $h$ is even and real-valued).

Comment: Do you disagree that any even function $h:[-1,1]\to \mathbb{R}$ with $|h|_2=1$ for which $I=\int_\mathbb{R} \frac{(h\ast h)(t)}{t^2} dt$ is minimal must be an eigenfunction as above? If we do agree: is $I$ the same for any such eigenfunction? If not, is there one for which $I?$ is minimal? What is $I$ then?

Comment: First of all, if $h * h(0) \ne 0$, then $I$ is infinite, is it not? Anyway, I do not want to enter the discussion about the other question, mostly due to time limitations, sorry.

Comment: That was a typo for $\int \frac{(h\ast h)(t)-1}{t^2} dt$, sorry.

Comment: At any rate, yes, that quantity is minimal for the eigenfunction corresponding to the lowest eigenvalue $\lambda$; it is then $\pi \lambda$.

Comment: @MateuszKwaśnicki Do you have a plot of the eigenfunction corresponding to the lowest eigenvalue?

Comment: Not at hand, but it looks like $\sqrt{1-x^2}$ near the boundary and it is a bit more flat in the interior.

Comment: I'm extremely unsurprised :). I was trying to construct the solution in my peasant-like way, in the form f(x) sqrt(1-x^2), where $f$ is given by a power series with radius of convergence >= 1 and derivatives that also have radius of convergence>=1.